# Datos de un Spinner entre activities

Tags: android, android-studio, spinner, android-spinner

Me gustaría saber como hacer que un `Spinner` vuelva a cargar los datos que tenia cuando vuelvo de otro `Activity`. Es decir, yo tengo un `Activity 1` con un `Spinner` y botón para pasar al `Activity 2`, en ese `Activity 2` hay un botón para volver atrás y mostrar los datos que había anteriormente en el `Spinner`.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta y añadir la parte del código a la que estás haciendo referencia para que alguien pueda ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes pasarle los datos que quieras con un Intent y recogerlos desde la otra actividad con getIntent te pongo un link donde se explicac como hacerlo : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265913/how-to-use-putextra-and-getextra-for-string-data

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado.